# Track completion of Google Calendar events

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

My typical case is following. When I need to check/do something in future (let's say in a month) I add an appropriate event in Google Calendar. The problem with it is that it's inconvenient to check if I missed some reminder recently: I don't want to examine each event every time.

Currently I change event color (to gray) to mark it completed. Are there any better ways?

Comment: You could add it to the todo bar

Comment: Google Calendar is probably the wrong tool for this. You should use a task manager that offers reminders. If you want to stay in the Google realm, Google Keep might be useful. Or you can do what you want with Inbox by Gmail; simply email yourself a message and use the "snooze" tool and define when you want the reminder sent.